# What is this output stage?

Tags: terminology

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Yy2D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've been calling this push-pull but apparently "push pull" is another name for totem pole now.

Comment: This is still a push/pull output :) I don't know if it's still used as an output stage. I've been seeing those in tube amps only. `but apparently "push pull" is another name for totem pole now` Probably a misusage. Actually there is a big difference between the two.

Comment: It's used extensively in forward converters in power supplies.

Comment: @AndyAka this configuration in forward converters? How? As output?

Comment: @RohatKılıç: [push-pull forward converter circuits courtesy of google images](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1DIMC_enGB828GB828&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ALeKk02Ys2vj0LZ0Hq5kZZjZRNNpN4PSAg%3A1584006478621&sa=1&ei=TgVqXtDRJdSW8gKg9QU&q=push+pull+forward+converter+circuit&oq=push+pull+forward+converter+circuit&gs_l=img.3...27910.30772..31073...0.0..0.54.508.11......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39j0.KA3P3orsej0&ved=0ahUKEwjQsOv705ToAhVUi1wKHaB6AQAQ4dUDCAc&uact=5)

Comment: Yes, it common circuit for the transformer driver in forwards converters up to several hundered watts (up until the copper savings or efficiency gains that can be got by going full bridge change the topology again)  it's also similar to drive for many latching relays, and unipolar stepper motors.

Comment: @AndyAka I knew that they are called "push pull converter" only. But I didn't know they are also called "push pull **forward** converter". Thanks.

Comment: a forwards converter takes current out of the secondary side of a transformer at the same time that it is put into the primary side.  af flyback converter takes current out of the secondary side of a coupled inductor after it has stopped being fed into the primary side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration you've shown is the prototypical 'push-pull' arrangement.

I can understand why somebody might describe a totem pole output stage as a push-pull, but most people call it a totem pole. They are totally different circuit used in totally different situations.

It's likely the person has heard the term push-pull, and their first exposure to a circuit that had a 'drive in both directions' sort of behaviour was a totem pole. I'm sympathetic to the mistake, I might even have used words like that when explaining the how and why of a totem pole output to somebody.

It's how language develops, it might even catch on. However it grates to those who use the 'old terms' 'correctly'. A better name for a push-pull output stage would be a 'see-saw' configuration. It describes the picture it makes very well, rather than describing the behaviour, and brooks no confusion with a totem pole, which was named after the picture it made.

Don't get hung up on names, it's the behaviour of the circuit that matters. Well chosen and consistently used names are a useful shorthand. But when the usage is debased, they get misused and confusing, and we have to revert to longer ways to describe what we mean.

Answer (score 3):

Neil has already discussed some things. I'll add one additional comment which is more directly related to the circuit you show and it's more common function within a larger system. (And yes, it's push-pull arrangement just as Neil and Rohat have already mentioned.)

In the 1950's HAM radio operators using their cars as a base station and both car and farm radio receivers had to operate off of "DC car batteries" for power. They often used a mechanical "vibrator" (see [here](https://www.tubesandmore.com/products/vibrator-4-pin-automobile-radio) for a simpler example of one of these devices), together with a transformer, in order to generate the higher plate voltages required by vacuum tube circuits at the time. In the late 1950's and after, lower voltage vacuum tubes and transistors took over for much of the radio receiver part of the market. HAM radio, of course, requires quite substantial plate voltages and that continued the need for these mechanical vibrators for a while.

When I was growing up, I'd find myself replacing worn out mechanical vibrators with new ones not frequently, but also not infrequently. I also scavenged them from wrecked cars of the day.

[A very nice video from Mr. Carlson's Lab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bROZ4hGisgM&list=PL00k29EUvE3NTIiZNWfzsJjwg5gxr6Mfm&index=30&t=1216s) provides an excellent way to see how this all works. I've set the video to start with the mechanical vibrator, itself. You can go [earlier in the video where the schematic is discussed](https://youtu.be/bROZ4hGisgM?t=513) to see this kind of circuit in no less than ***two*** places in this schematic. One of them is for the power supply itself and uses the mechanical vibrator I mentioned. Another is in the upper-right corner of the schematic where Mr. Carlson will soon place his fingers when talking about the class-AB amplifier stage, as well. This video is an excellent source of information related to this kind of stage you have, which uses similar ideas to perform two completely different functions.

So, from the above video and schematic, I think you can see that this concept is not only used in class-AB stages where a transformer may be required to match impedances better, but it is also used in power supplies, too. And that's just two uses.

The basic idea is to turn on one side, then turn that off and turn on the other side, in alternating fashion. With the positive voltage rail at the center-tap of the transformer, this treats the center-tapped primary as two separate and similarly sized primary coils, operated in alternately opposing directions, just as an AC source would do with a single primary coil. There will be different design considerations if it is being used to drive a power supply transformer vs a class-AB push-pull transformer impedance-matching driver circuit. But the basic ideas are close enough to be grouped.

It's push-pull, just as you say.